# Symfony LockHandler

Tags: symfony

I am thinking about using the LockHandler but have a question. Will a lock prohibit the same command from being run within a different instance of a project? In other words, I may be running multiple instances of my project on one server under different VHOSTs. (ie www.instance1.com & www.instance2.com)If I setup a cron job for each project to run the command "app:cron" would the first project that executes the command stop the other project from running its "app:cron" command if they happened to overlap each other or even fire at the same time?

If so, when I construct the lockhandler should I just inject an instance specific name into the constructor?

ie

First Instance:

```
new LockHandler('instance1.hello.lock');
```

Second Instance:

```
new LockHandler('instance2.hello.lock');
```

@Kadriles answer below is correct, Just to add, for anyone else looking into this.

The LockHandler uses the PHP function sys_get_temp_dir() to get the temp folder to use. It creates files in the following format (using my instance1 example above): sf.instance1-hello-lock.[64CHAR HASH].lock
When you create a lock Symfony "opens" the file so the filessytem sees the file is in use, when it releases it, it "closes" the file but does not actually delete it - this threw me off for a couple minutes.

I ended up creating a parameter for the host and prepending that to the name used in the constructor like so:

```
$host = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('router.request_context.host');
new LockHandler($host . '.hello.lock');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LockHandler` creates a file in your temp directory.

It is not related with VHOST.

So if all your VHOSTs run on the same system (and the same temp directory), you have to use different lock names if you don't want any VHOST to lock others.